# jQuery .replacewith ruby code

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have ruby code that calls a method to accept a candidate for a vacancy like this:

```
<%= link_to "Accept", accept_candidate_path(vacancy_id: @vacancy.id, employee_id: e.id), method: :post, :remote => true, :id => "link_#{i}" %>
```

The method changes the state in the database to Accepted.

Once that is clicked, I want to replace that with following ruby code:

```
<%= link_to "Cancel", back_to_pending_path(vacancy_id: @vacancy.id, employee_id: e.id), method: :post, :remote => true%>
```

I also have a if/else that checks the state of a candidate to display either links. But that is only triggered by refreshing the page and I just want it to accept it, change the button without completely refreshing the page.

Currently I have this:

```
$("[id^='link_']").click(function (event) {
  $(this).replaceWith("Accepted")
});
```

and it works completly fine with just plain text, but I need the text to be the embedded ruby. Is this possible?

Comment: You have quite a number of options here.
1) show/hide both links and just toggle them depending. i.e.: show accept; when click accept, hide accept and show cancel.
2) add a `accept.js.erb` file and add the javascript here. "Unobtrusive javascript" - http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#server-side-concerns
3. Handle the link via AJAX in a javascript file and return a partial (via controller) with the new link. 

it'll take some time to type all these up with examples, but I will if you would like.

Comment: use a data atribute on the elements and read that value

Comment: Yep, I should have included that in my list @charlietfl. And to add the to data-attribute, you could even group the controller methods into one and accept/cancel depending on current state, so you wouldn't have to change much client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it works completly fine with just plain text, but I need the text to be the embedded ruby. Is this possible?

You have to create `.js` files for your action where you can change the html of link with paths as well

e.g 
create `accept_candidate.js.erb` and add respond_to js format it will do the trick

```
# accept_candidate.js.erb
$("[id^='link_']").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('cancel_link')) %>")


# _cancel_link.html.erb
<%= link_to "Cancel", back_to_pending_path(vacancy_id: @vacancy.id, employee_id: e.id), method: :post, :remote => true%>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, one small issue there, I am getting the employee_id in a loop in my view and thus I get the error undefined local variable or method `e' for #<#<Class:0x007fdd840e2ab8>:0x007fdd83ca80b0> with the parameters employer_id and vacancy_id, and I need the employee_id aswell to target the correct row to change.

Comment: you need to set `@employee` object from accept/candidate action  that so that it will be available in your views and then change `e.id` to `@employee.id`

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks!